# chromedriver.exe process still exists in task manager even after using driver.quit()

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

We've noticed a problem when trying to execute chromedriver tests in the Java platform, where the `chromedriver.exe` process actually still exists  in task manager even after using `driver.quit()` or `driver.close()`.

And yes, if we use `taskkill /im chromedriver.exe /f` after script execution, then **`chromedriver.exe` process is getting killed.**

But we want to avoid using `taskkill` command due to other dependencies in our framework. Hence please let us know if this issue is handled at selenium side? In which version?

Or suggest if we need to follow any other steps to make `driver.quit()` will kill the entry from taskmanager as well.

Environment details:

```
selenium version: 2.53
chrome driver: 2.40
java version: 1.8_131 (64 bit.)
```

Comment: try: `driver.close();` just before you call `driver.quit() ;`

Answer (score 0):

> You should probably close the driver before quit:

```
    driver.close();
    driver.quit();
```

this will close all the chrome.exe plus chromedriver.exe

Answer (score 0):

use driver.quit(); to kill the chromedriver.exe process...
i know sometimes it wont work,  will tell you what is the reason. You might have written below code.
**driver = null;

driver.quit();**
but this is wrong. Use below code
**driver.quit();
driver = null;**
**the above code will work.**